# Pulling Merge Fields that contain HTML into an email template

Tags: email-template, merge-field

I have a RTF with html code in it:

`<button>Click Me</button>`

When I create an HTML Email template and use the merged field:

```
{!Object.Field__c}
```

The output in the template is simply:

```
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Where if I type the html in to the template directly it works.

It there any way to pull in a mergeField containing HTML and have it display as if it was typed into the template?

When using a VF Template it still outputs like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you use a Visualforce Email Template, you can use `<apex:outputText value="{!Object.Field__c}" escape="false"/>`

You cannot do it without using a Visualforce Email Template

Comment: Unfortunately the output is the same, the <button>xxxxx</button> is rendered exactly as it is written and does not show a button....

Comment: I don't think the `<button>` tag is supported in HTML emails: http://www.pinpointe.com/blog/email-campaign-html-and-css-support